# Comparing Times From 2 Different Lists With Nested For-Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

In my code, I have a list named `stamp` and a list named `focal`. Both lists have time stamps in them and I need to find the last time stamp in `stamp` and is larger than each `focal` but smaller than the next element in `focal` and append it to a list called `times`

Here is a small sample set from each list:

- `stamp`

`['2018-07-21,11:37:37', '2018-07-21,11:37:48', '2018-07-21,11:37:52', '2018-07-21,11:38:12', '2018-07-21,11:38:45', '2018-07-21,11:39:04', '2018-07-21,11:39:51', '2018-07-21,11:41:36', '2018-07-21,11:41:52', '2018-07-21,11:42:01', '2018-07-21,11:42:24', '2018-07-21,11:42:27', '2018-07-21,11:43:01', '2018-07-21,11:43:56', '2018-07-21,11:44:13', '2018-07-21,11:44:24', '2018-07-21,11:45:20', '2018-07-21,11:45:32', '2018-07-21,11:45:40', '2018-07-21,11:45:51', '2018-07-21,11:46:20', '2018-07-21,11:46:36', '2018-07-21,11:49:01', '2018-07-21,11:50:12', '2018-07-21,11:50:45', '2018-07-21,11:51:16', '2018-07-21,11:51:32', '2018-07-21,11:51:47', '2018-07-21,11:52:10', '2018-07-21,11:52:13', '2018-07-21,11:52:16', '2018-07-21,11:52:19', '2018-07-21,11:53:22']`

- `focal`

  `['2018-07-21,11:37:20', '2018-07-21,11:52:57']`

So the item that would be appended to `times` is `[2018-07-21,11:52:19]`

The code I currently have to do this is:

`for x in range(len(focal)-1):
        for y in range(len(stamp)):
            if focal[x] <= stamp[y] and stamp[y] < focal[x+1]:
                times.append(stamp[y])`

but it does not do what I want and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Are these lists both guaranteed to be in sorted order?

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to stamp element being in between the max and min of focal?

Comment: @abarnert yes they will always be sorted in order

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you are appending all larger than focal[x] but smaller than focal[x+1]. If you only want to append the last element with this property, try this:

```
for x in range(len(focal)-1):
    for y in range(len(stamp)-1):
        if focal[x] <= stamp[y] and stamp[y] < focal[x+1] and stamp[y+1] >= focal[x+1]:
            times.append(stamp[y])
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops are hard to read for that. Use a list comprehension.

The first step is to formalize your requirement so it's easy to understand. Basically you want to find all elements for which `focal[x] < stamp < focal[x+1]` and take the highest.

With a list comprehension this is one line:

```
max([x for x in stamp if focal[x] < x < focal[x+1]])
```

This code also works if the values in `stamp` are not sorted.

Put in a loop:

```
for x in range(len(focal)-1):
    times.append(max([x for x in stamp if focal[x] < x < focal[x+1]]))
```

If you actually want the last (as opposed to the latest) value in `stamp` in the range given by focal, you can get it like this:

```
[x for x in stamp if focal[x] < x < focal[x+1]][-1]
```

Besides that, note that string comparison for dates may not be super-reliable, depending on your data. It's just alphabetical comparison. Consider storing your dates as some kind of date type.

Comment: The ISO Y-M-D H:M:S formats were specifically designed so they _are_ sortable as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

stamp = ['2018-07-21,11:37:37', '2018-07-21,11:37:48', '2018-07-21,11:37:52', '2018-07-21,11:38:12', '2018-07-21,11:38:45', '2018-07-21,11:39:04', '2018-07-21,11:39:51', '2018-07-21,11:41:36', '2018-07-21,11:41:52', '2018-07-21,11:42:01', '2018-07-21,11:42:24', '2018-07-21,11:42:27', '2018-07-21,11:43:01', '2018-07-21,11:43:56', '2018-07-21,11:44:13', '2018-07-21,11:44:24', '2018-07-21,11:45:20', '2018-07-21,11:45:32', '2018-07-21,11:45:40', '2018-07-21,11:45:51', '2018-07-21,11:46:20', '2018-07-21,11:46:36', '2018-07-21,11:49:01', '2018-07-21,11:50:12', '2018-07-21,11:50:45', '2018-07-21,11:51:16', '2018-07-21,11:51:32', '2018-07-21,11:51:47', '2018-07-21,11:52:10', '2018-07-21,11:52:13', '2018-07-21,11:52:16', '2018-07-21,11:52:19', '2018-07-21,11:53:22']
focal = ['2018-07-21,11:37:20', '2018-07-21,11:52:57']

print([*takewhile(lambda v: focal[0] < v < focal[1], stamp)][-1])
```

Output:

```
2018-07-21,11:52:19
```